# PyEphem installation error

Tags: python, pyephem

Any help with installing ephem?

With this as part of script

> ... install ephem Downloading/unpacking ephem   Downloading
>   ephem-3.7.6.0.tar.gz (739kB): 739kB downloaded   Running setup.py
>   (path:/tmp/pip-build-azhohn/ephem/setup.py) egg_info for package ephem
>        Installing collected packages: ephem   Running setup.py install for ephem

I get this error:

> unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-build-azhohn/ephem/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ZWO0wl-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-azhohn/ephem
>   Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log

This is an installation on a Raspberry with OSMC operation system.